# Python Default Argument List -- Inconsistent behavior

Tags: python, list, function

I have a situation in which the value of the default argument in a function head is affected by an if-clause within the function body. I am using Python 3.7.3.

## function definitions

We have two functions `f` and `j`. I understand the behavior of the first two function. I don't understand the second function's behavior.

```py
def f(L=[]):
    print('f, inside:   ', L)
    L.append(5)
    return L

def j(L=[]):
    print('j, before if:', L)
    if L == []:
        L = []
    print('j, after if: ', L)
    L.append(5)
    return L
```

## function behavior that I understand

Now we call the first function three times:

```py
>>> print('f, return:   ', f())
f, inside:    []
f, return:    [5]
>>> print('f, return:   ', f())
f, inside:    [5]
f, return:    [5, 5]
>>> print('f, return:   ', f())
f, inside:    [5, 5]
f, return:    [5, 5, 5]
```

The empty list `[]` is initialized on the first call of the function. When we append `5` to `L` then the one instance of the list in the memory is modified. Hence, on the second function call, this modified list is assigned to `L`. Sounds reasonable.

## function behavior that I don't unterstand

Now, we call the third function (`j`) and get:

```py
>>> print('j, return:   ', j())
j, before if: []
j, after if:  []
j, return:    [5]
>>> print('j, return:   ', j())
j, before if: []
j, after if:  []
j, return:    [5]
>>> print('j, return:   ', j())
j, before if: []
j, after if:  []
j, return:    [5]
```

According to the output, `L` is an empty list in the beginning of each call of the function `j`. When I remove the if-clause, in the body of function `j` the function is equal to function `f` and yields the same output. Hence, the if-clause seems to have some side effect. Testing for `len(L) == 0` instead of `L == []` in `j` has the same effect.

## related to

My question is related to:

- Stackoverflow Question [Python Default Arguments Evaluation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32326777/python-default-arguments-evaluation)
- Stackoverflow Question ["Least Astonishment" and the Mutable Default Argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132941/least-astonishment-and-the-mutable-default-argument) and
- the [Python Tutorial Section 4.7.1. (Default Argument Values)](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#default-argument-values)

But the answers to these question and the tutorial answer only, what I already know.

Comment: This would be easier to follow if you would you post _one_ function whose behaviour you don't understand, explain your problem with it, and leave out all the other functions.

Comment: It's unclear to me why that was unexpected/contrary. Were you expecting `L = []` inside the function to change the bound default value?

Comment: @khelwood I removed the fourth function.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I would expect that the function `j` has the same return value than function `f`. However, it does not. The print statements in the function body are for `debugging`.

Comment: But *why* did you expect that? What was your hypothesis for how that would work that led you to expect the same behaviour?

Comment: @daniel.neumann I meant leave out _all_ the other functions, except the one you are asking about. And explain clearly why the behaviour confuses you.

Comment: @khelwood updated accordingly.

Comment: @jonrsharpe The `L` becomes differently initialized depending on the `if` clause in the function body. Please compare the lines `f, inside` and `j, before if` after the second call of `f` and `j`. In `f` the `L` is a list with value `5` in it. In `j` the `L` is an empty list. However, it should be a list `[5]`.

Comment: *Why* should it be? Again, *"Were you expecting `L = []` inside the function to change the bound default value?"* (or `L = [5]` the same) At the moment you seem to be asking *"what's the difference between appending multiple items to a single list and appending a single item each to multiple lists"*, and the answer seems obvious, so I'm trying to understand where your understanding departs what's happening.

Comment: @jonrsharpe PART 1: An empty list `[]` is initialized on the first call of the function `f`. The default for `L` is: point to this empty list. In the body of `f`, we append a value to the list and return it. On the second call of `f`, the empty list `[]` is not newly initialized but `L` points to the location in memory where the empty list was originally initialized. Since the first call of `f` this list is not empty anymore. Therefore, `L` does not have the value of an empty list but a list with one value. If we call `f` ten times, we will end up with a list of ten elements.

Comment: @daniel.neumann no, *per [the question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132941/least-astonishment-and-the-mutable-default-argument) you've linked to* the empty list is initialised when the function is *created*, not when it's first called.

Comment: @jonrsharpe PART 2: Now we look into `j`. I expected `j` to work the same way. At least the print statement before the `if`-clause should yield `[5]` in the second call of `j`.

Comment: @jonrsharpe While I am typing these comments, the question was answered by glibdud . The list (towards which `L` points to) that is modified in `j` is not the list set as default value.

Comment: It feels like you could just have answered "yes" either time I asked and saved quite a bit of typing. The same answer was provided a while ago by Jean-François too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modify your print statements to also print `id(L)`:

```
def j(L=[]):
    print('j, before if:', L, id(L))
    if L == []:
        L = []
    print('j, after if: ', L, id(L))
    L.append(5)
    return L
```

Now check your results:

```
>>> j()
j, before if: [] 2844163925576
j, after if:  [] 2844163967688
[5]
```

Note the difference in the IDs. By the time you get to the portion of the function where you modify `L`, *it no longer refers to the same object as the default argument*. You've rebound `L` to a new list (with the `L = []` in the body of the if statement), and as a result, you are never changing the default argument.

Answer (score 1):

if all boils down to this:

```
if L == [5]:
    L = []
```

Here you're not changing the value of the default argument, just binding locally to a new name.

You can do that instead:

```
if L == [5]:
    L.clear()
```

or

```
if L == [5]:
    L[:] = []
```

to clear the data of the parameter object.

Comment: My irritation is related to the function `j` where we test `if L == []`.

Comment: it's the same thing. The problem is that L name is reassigned (same thing repeated in the accepted answer BTW)

Answer (score 1):

```
def a():
    print "assigning default value"
    return []

def b(x=a()):
    x.append(10)
    print "inside b",x
    return x

print b()
print b()
print b()
```

try running this. You'll see that default value is not assigned every time you run the function
OUTPUT

```
assigning default value
inside b [10]
[10]
inside b [10, 10]
[10, 10]
inside b [10, 10, 10]
[10, 10, 10]
```

only once it called the 'a' function to the default value. rest is very well explained above about the compilation of a method so not repeating the same

Comment: used python 2.7 so check syntax for print if you are executing on pytohn 3 or above